# How can I match a literal value in a macro called from another macro?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

How can I pass `true` or `false` through a macro and into another macro, where the inner macro matches on `true` or `false`?  Not `expr`, but literally `true` or `false`.

When I do the following, I can't find the correct syntax to match against the boolean token:

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! true_false {
    (true) => { // < ------------- I really want the match to be at this level
        println!("true!");
    };
    (false) => {// < ------------- or here
        println!("false!");
    };
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! intermediary {
    ($boolean:literal) => { // < -- Is there token type I can set here?
        crate::true_false!($boolean);
    }
}

fn main() {
    crate::intermediary!(true);
    crate::intermediary!(false);
}
```

I realize that I can use `match` *inside* the inner macro and that the "constant propagation" compiler optimization will nuke the branch I don't care about.  However, I want the inner branch to have the same block scope as the block the `intermediary` macro is being called at.

*This may be [x-y problem space](https://xyproblem.info/), but despite my actual problem, I'm wondering if there is syntax to solve the problem I presented above.*

Comment: You might be able to fix it if you pretend you are not trying to match a literal and are instead matching a token instead (`$boolean:tt`). Also there is a typo in this example where `$boolen` is misspelled which would likely cause it to fail.

Comment: @Locke,  That was it!  Post an answer for unbelievably valuable street cred and fake internet points.

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same problem. After trying for almost half a day, I found changing `literal` to `tt` works. It will pass `true` as a token instead of a literal value, so you can match it in the next macro.

```rust
macro_rules! intermediary {
    ($boolean:tt) => { // < -- Is there token type I can set here?
        crate::true_false!($boolean);
    }
}
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros.html#macro-invocation

Comment: I use macro like this in static, so I can't use `match`.